# Snakemake: Use the value of another expand variable in declaration

Tags: snakemake

Is there a way to use the value of another expand variable in an expand function? For instance, if I had the following `config.yaml`

```
patients:
  patientA:
    - "sampleA_A"
    - "sampleA_B"
    - "sampleA_C"
  patientB:
    - "sampleB_A"
    - "sampleB_B"
    - "sampleB_C"
```

And this Snakefile

```
configfile: "config.yaml"
patient_samples = expand("{patient}_{sample}.txt", patient = "patientA", sample = config["patients"]["patientA"])
print(patient_samples)
```

This produces:

```
['patientA_sampleA_A.txt', 'patientA_sampleA_B.txt', 'patientA_sampleA_C.txt']
```

But if I want to iterate over the patients and have it match with the samples, I was hoping to be able to use the value of the expand patient variable to retrieve the patient's samples:

```
configfile: "config.yaml"
PATIENTS = ["patientA", "patientB"]
patient_samples = expand("{patient}_{sample}.txt", patient = PATIENTS, sample = config["patients"][patient])
print(patient_samples)
```

But this doesn't work as it produces the following error:

```
NameError in line 4 of /Users/fongchan/Downloads/Snakefile:
name 'patient' is not defined
  File "/Users/fongchan/Downloads/Snakefile", line 4, in <module>
```

Is there a way to reference the expand `patient` value so that it can be used in the `config` variable to grab the corresponding samples?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's easier if you move away from the `expand` function altogether and construct the `patient_samples` list yourself. E.g. something like:

```
patient_samples= []
for patient in config["patients"]:
    for sample in config["patients"][patient]:
        patient_samples.append("{patient}_{sample}.txt".format(patient= patient, sample= sample))
```